# Why is my relational query returning zero?

Tags: relatedto, elementquery, menu

I have an entries page structure section
Pages

And two structure sections / menus
Menu A
Menu B

Menu A and Menu B have an entry field link called 'entryLink' that is a relation to an entry in the page section

My url route looks like
page-1/page-2/page-3

I want to find the url first segment and locate it in the Menu A or Menu B entryLink field (so I can then play with children entries and same level items)

So I get the first segment, locate the page and create a query to find the relation.

First segment

```
{% set entryPage = craft.entries().slug(firstSlug).one() %}
```

Then query relation to get route

```
{% set menuItem = craft.entries.section('MenuB', 'MenuA')
            .relatedTo({
                targetElement: entryPage,
                field: 'entryLink'
            }).one() %}
```

check menu id for page accessed

```
{{ menuItem.id }}
```

This seems to work for a page that has a relation in Menu B.
However for Menu A menuItem.id returns zero. I have checked that the entries exist and are related in Menu A
Is there something wrong with my query?

==== SOLVED ====

Answer was changing

```
{% set entryPage = craft.entries().slug(firstSlug).one() %}
```

to

```
{% set entryPage = craft.entries.section('Pages').slug(firstSlug).one() %}
```

Not sure why this worked

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is probably that your syntax for the [`section()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#section) query parameter is a bit off.

Currently, you're passing the section handles `'MenuB'` and `'MenuA'` as separate arguments to the `section()` query parameter – i.e. `section('MenuB', 'MenuA')`. However, the `section()` parameter actually only takes a single argument, which is why the query ignores the second `'MenuA'` handle.

When querying multiple sections you should either pass the section handles as an array:

`section(['MenuB', 'MenuA'])`

...or as a comma-separated string:

`section('MenuB,MenuA')`

Comment: Thanks Mats. Oddly enough that didn't change the outcome. However i did get the expected outcome when i specified the targetElement query to {% set entryPage = craft.entries.section('Pages').slug(firstSlug).one() %}